Is there a way to make a `ChangeNotifier` listen to another `ChangeNotifier` in a flutter app?
Is there a way to make a ChangeNotifier listen to another ChangeNotifier in a flutter app?
something like this:
class FirstCounter extends ChangeNotifier {
    int _i = 0;
    void increment() {
        i = i + 1;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

class SecoundCounter extends ChangeNotifier {
    int _i = 0;
    void increment() {
        i = i + 1;
        notifyListeners();
    }

    void listen() {
        var resetCallback = () { i = 0;}
        FirstCounter.listen(resetCallback);
    }
}

I want SecoundCounter to reset when FirstCounter is updated.

the listening is done with addListener - you need to call it on FirstCounter object

use first.addListener(second.reset);
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstCounter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int i = 0;
  void increment() {
    i = i + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class SecondCounter extends ChangeNotifier {
  int i = 0;

  void increment() {
    i = i + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void reset() {
    i = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CounterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CounterWidget> createState() => _CounterWidgetState();
}

class _CounterWidgetState extends State<CounterWidget> {
  final FirstCounter first = FirstCounter();
  final SecondCounter second = SecondCounter();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    first.addListener(second.reset);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    first.dispose();
    second.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              ListenableBuilder(
                  listenable: first,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Text("${first.i}");
                  }),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  first.increment();
                },
                child: Text("First"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              ListenableBuilder(
                  listenable: second,
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Text("${second.i}");
                  }),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  second.increment();
                },
                child: Text("Second"),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I use the Provider package: ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) {
return FirstCounter();
},
),
do you know how I can put myself in a similar configuration?

You could try something like create: (context) { return FirstCounter()..addListener(second.reset); }

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class Counter1 extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;

  int get counter {
    return _counter;
  }

  void increment() {
    _counter = _counter + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void reset() {
    _counter = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Counter2 extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;

  int get counter {
    return _counter;
  }

  void increment() {
    _counter = _counter + 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MultiProvider(providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) {
            return Counter2();
          },
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Counter2, Counter1>(
          create: (context) {
            return Counter1();
          },
          update: (BuildContext context, Counter2 value, Counter1? previous) {
            if (previous == null) {
              throw StateError("Counter1 is null");
            }
            value.removeListener(previous.reset); // To avoid multiple listener
            value.addListener(previous.reset);
            return previous;
          },
        ),
      ], child: const MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var counter1 = Provider.of<Counter1>(context);
    var counter2 = Provider.of<Counter2>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title:
            const Text("Let's try to reset counter 1 when counter 2 increment"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Counter 1:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter1.counter}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: counter1.increment,
                child: const Text("Increment counter 1")),
            const Text(
              'Counter 2:',
            ),
            Text(
              '${counter2.counter}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: counter2.increment,
                child: const Text("Increment counter 2")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


